# A stack of function pointers: how to call the function?

Tags: c++, function, stack

I have a stack of function pointers (all of void type & with no parameters). I am having difficulty finding out how I then call/execute a function that is in the stack?

**If you look at the simple example below everthing compiles & works except for the last line**

```
typedef class InstructionScreen;
typedef void (InstructionScreen::*MemberFuncPtr)();
stack <MemberFuncPtr> instructionStep;              // This is how I declare it. Works
instructionStep.push( &InstructionScreen::step1 );  // This is how I add the member function step(). Works
(*instructionStep.top())();                         // How do I call the function now? This doesn't work
```

This is the whole code I am attempting to get to compile:

```
class InstructionScreen
{
     public:
         InstructionScreen()
         {
              instructionStep.push( &InstructionScreen::step1 );
              instructionStep.push( &InstructionScreen::step2 );   

              // add timer to call run instructions each 10 seconds        
         }

         void step1()
         {
         }

         void step2()
         {
         }

         void runInstructions()
         {
              if ( !instructionStep.empty() )
              {
                  *(instructionStep.top())(); 
                  instructionStep.pop();
              }
              // else kill timer
         }

     private:
          stack <MemberFuncPtr> instructionStep;   
};
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with a stack, it is "how to call a member function pointer".  Type that in the Search box.

Comment: You don't have "a stack of function pointers"  you have "a stack of pointers to member functions", and they aren't "all of `void` type & with no parameters", they all need an instance to operate on, after which they take no additional parameters and then return `void`.

Comment: It's important to grasp that member functions are not tied to any particular *object instance*, but rather to the *class*. Therefore, a member function pointer is just an abstract thing that cannot be used without also specifying a concrete object instance of that class. In short, *you* have to tell the compiler whose object's member you want to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an instance to call a member function.  Try this:

```
InstructionScreen screen;
MemberFuncPtr step = instructionStep.top();
(screen.*step)();
```

To run a function in the stack from within another member function, you can use:

```
MemberFuncPtr step = instructionStep.top();
(this->*step)();
```

Comment: How would I call the function from within the memeber function InstructionScreen::runInstructions()?